# Change pre-installed Skype.apk with a newer on on a Rooted device

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, installation, skype

### **Manipulation made with Device :**

- Rooted and Remounted the system.
- Removed old Skype version 4.0.xxxx (it is obsolete and can't connect even with internet connection).
- Deleted old APK and put another APK inside 5.0.0.xxxx `system/app`.
- chmod Skype.apk with 644.
- Factory Reset the device and try to launch the new APK.

### **Problem**

- The `Skype.APK` present in the appdrawer but does not start at all.
- logcat shows a loop the apk tries to start the the process die.

Comment: I think you forgot to put libs in system/lib you can extract them from the apk.

Comment: It should work. Did you try to use more permissions like 755 instead of 644? You could also try to just adb install youtube.apk. Why do you want it to be inside system/app?

Comment: @user3387542: even with 777 or 755 it did not work.